# Protobuf bytes is broken after MessageToDict method

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to convert protobuf message to python dict using [MessageToDict](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/json_format.py) method

But if I've serialized on server side dict {} (empty dict), after using **MessageToDict** instead of getting empty dict, I have - `BQAAAAA=`

What can be wrong?

Comment: just to confirm: `BQAAAAA=` is definitely invalid as a protobuf payload

Comment: @MarcGravell it's output after MessageToDict(), in protobuf it is OK bytestring.